# JBoss 7.1.1 doesn't start because of unexpected element "pool"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

I get the following error message when I add the pool element:

> Caused by: org.jboss.as.connector.util.ParserException: IJ010061:
>   Unexpected element: pool

If I remove the pool element it works. I have checked the XSD in the docs folder and I am pretty sure this is right? Why does it fail?

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter>
                <archive>
                    jackrabbit-jca-2.6.2.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/jca/JcrRepository" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="jackrabbit-jca-2_6_2_rar-Pool" use-ccm="true">
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>4</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
                   </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
            </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: The xml is definitely valid against [this schema](http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-as-resource-adapters_1_0.xsd). Double check to make sure you don't have any version/dependency issues.

Comment: Using xa-pool element instead works. Seems like it is some validation after the schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature ;)

...

Let's just go a little bit deep into the responsible implementation:

When you look into the source of the responsible parser you can see the following

```
     case TRANSACTION_SUPPORT: {
                         if (txSupportMatched) {
                            throw new ParserException(bundle.unexpectedElement(TRANSACTIONSUPPORT.getXmlName()));
                        }
                        String value = rawElementText(reader);
                        TRANSACTIONSUPPORT.parseAndSetParameter(value, operation, reader);
                        isXa = value != null && TransactionSupportEnum.valueOf(value) == TransactionSupportEnum.XATransaction;
                        txSupportMatched = true;
                        break;
                    }
```

That's the parsing of the resource-adapter-tag. If you write the XATransaction-keyword, the (by default false) isXa-var switches to true.

Now the parser of the connection-definition-tag expects a xa-pool-tag

```
           case XA_POOL: {
                        if (! isXa) throw new ParserException(bundle.unexpectedElement(CommonConnDef.Tag.XA_POOL.name()));
                        if (poolDefined)
                            throw new ParserException(bundle.multiplePools());
                        parseXaPool(reader, connectionDefinitionNode);
                        poolDefined = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    case POOL: {
                        if (isXa) throw new ParserException(bundle.unexpectedElement(CommonConnDef.Tag.POOL.name()));
                        if (poolDefined)
                            throw new ParserException(bundle.multiplePools());
                        parsePool(reader, connectionDefinitionNode);
                        poolDefined = true;
                        break;
                    }
```

Depending on the XATransaction-definition the ironjacamar-impl create different pool-implementations. And the xa-poolType of the schema allows more configuration then the standard-pooltype.

But I think that should be documented somewhere, at least in the schema.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Good question and you are totally right. This is a valid according to the schema and I guess this is a bug of JBoss 7.11 .You can file a bug on this . I think you can continue with using a previous version of JBoss and this issue won't be there.

Comment: Using xa-pool element instead works. Seems like it is some validation after the schema?

Comment: you use xs-pool when using XA data source I guess and you need XA data source for clustering purposes according to what I've heard. Anyway if it is working for you then go ahead with it. But my suggestion is to use a previous version of JBoss and continue is better rather going with complex stuff.